# SQLalchemy. I get only one result for this query

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I have this python code that creates a table called Events

```
class Events(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'events'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(25), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(30), nullable=True)
    phone_number = Column(String(15), nullable=True)
    venue = Column(String(70), nullable=True)
    description = Column(String(2000), nullable=True)
    date = Column(String(15), nullable=True)
    time = Column(String(10),nullable=True)
    duration = Column(String(25),nullable=True)
    who_made_me = Column(String(25),nullable=True)
    address = Column(String(50),nullable=True)
```

and after adding events y, and ye

```
   add = Events(name = "y")
   add_two = Events(name = "ye")
   con.add(add,add_two)
   con.commit()
```

I want to search for y and get both results. I tried to use:

```
search_results= con.query(Events).filter(Events.name.like("y")).all()
```

and I only get one result, "y", I would want any result that's similar to "y" like "ye" or "yr".

What query method do I use?

Answer (score 0):

Try with '%' after y.

```
search_results= con.query(Events).filter(Events.name.like("y%")).all()
```

Let us know whether it works.

Comment: Nope, still returns only one result

Comment: can you add the import statements too, so i can check the reference classes properly. and specify which database software you are using too.

Comment: from DB import * my DB file

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///users.db')
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
con = DBSession()

using SQLite

Answer (score 0):

You only get one results in your DB because you only commit one event with your session. Try:

```
add = Events(name = "y")
add_two = Events(name = "ye")
con.add(add)
con.add(add_two)
con.commit()
```

Comment: This is not the case, both of them exist. I checked by querying them seperately

Comment: What do you get with: `con.query(Events).all()` ? I get only one Event

Comment: I added them separately. and still the query doesn't work.